# Custom confirmation window on firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to throw a custom confirmation window while closing the firefox (or) IE window if it has unsaved data in the form. But this issue is not happening in chrome browser.
I did overridden the onbeforeunload event, but firefox throws two confirmation window, one is my custom confirmation and other is 
firefox confirmation window, i want to restrict the confirmation window thrown by firefox i want only my custom confirmation.I have given the code snippet below,

```
function unloadPage(){ 
    if(unsaved){ 
        return confirm(getMessage(kradVariables.MESSAGE_KEY_DIRTY_FIELDS)); 
    } 
} 
window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
```

Thanks, 
Prem Kumar B

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a string in onbeforeunload handler and calls to confirm(), alert() and prompt() are ignored there. The returned string will then de presented to the user among with two buttons, where he then either stays on the page or leaves it.

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm(), and
>   window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
    if(unsaved) { 
        return getMessage(kradVariables.MESSAGE_KEY_DIRTY_FIELDS);
    } 
};
```

Comment: Basically i want throw custom message on the confirmation popup while closing the browser window, I tried by removing confirm(), just returning the string message, but still am not able to view the custom message on the confirmation popup both in Firefox and IE window.onbeforeunload = function()
    if(unsaved) { 
        return "Do you want to close";
    } 
};

Comment: Maybe unsaved is falsey?